# Issue with Saving Options from First Request in PHP wodpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have encountered an issue in my PHP code where it is not saving the option from the first request but instead saving it from the second request. I am using the following code:

```
// Add ajax action for authenticated users
add_action( "wp_ajax_SavingProductTitleArray", "SavingProductTitleArray" );

// Add ajax action for non-authenticated users
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_SavingProductTitleArray", "SavingProductTitleArray" );

// Function to handle saving product title array
function SavingProductTitleArray(){

  // Creating an instance of MyCoreProducts class
  $data = new MyCoreProducts();

  // Check if 'scan' variable is set to 1 in POST data
  if (isset($_POST['scan']) && $_POST['scan'] == 1) {
  
    // Get the existing product title array from plugin options
    global $my_plugin_opts;
    $old_products = $my_plugin_opts['my_plugin_option_product'];

    // Get the new product title array from MyCoreProducts class method
    $new_data =  $data->getProductsTitleArray();

    // If no existing product array is found, create a new one
    if (empty($old_products) || !isset($old_products)) {
    
      // Check if 'myplugin_opts' option exists
      if (get_option('myplugin_opts') !== false) {
      
        // Get existing plugin options
        $my_plugin_option = get_option('myplugin_opts');
        
        // Update the product title array in the options
        $my_plugin_option['my_plugin_option_product'] = $new_data;
        update_option('myplugin_opts', $my_plugin_option);
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting the option to be saved from the first request, but it seems like it is not working as intended.

I have tried debugging the code and checking the values of $old_products and $new_data, but I have not been able to identify the issue.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the option is saved from the first request. Thank you in advance for your help.)

Comment: This lacks so much context ... We have no idea what exactly you are trying to achieve here in the first place; we don't know what request you are actually making from the frontend, where & when; we don't know what your `MyCoreProducts` class and its methods do; ...